# Adding only specific lines from a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to add specific lines from a text file into a dictionary. The idea would be to add all the lines beginning with AUD into an AUD dictionary, with their keys. Then CAD and down the list.

I've tried a few variants from searching and adding little bits. I'm as curious about answer as I am the errors and what they mean as I am learning. I am at the begining of Python and apologise if my attempts make your eyes bleed. Very grateful for your time.

This is the format of the .txt file [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VW8H5PZH)

This adds everything to a dictionary, I only want AUD

```
with open('rates.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    if  line.startswith('AUD') == True: # returns true on pairs I want to add
    AUD = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f) #adds everything
    else:
        pass
print AUD
```

Next I tried this which returned "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

```
AUD = {}
with open("rates.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('AUD'):
        (key, val) = line.split(' ') #The space inbetween the '' causes the error?
        AUD[int(key)] = val 
print AUD
```

and lastly I was working on this which returns 'KeyError: 'AUD_CHF'

```
AUD = {}
with open("rates.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'AUD_' in line:
            key, value = line.strip().split('')
            AUD [key].append(value)   
print AUD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close in you first example.

You don't need the `== True` in the `if` statement because `str.startswith()` returns a boolean which is evaulated by the `if`. Along with that I corrected some indentation.

```
AUD = {}
with open('rates.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('AUD'):
            split_line = line.split()
            AUD[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
        else:
            pass
print AUD
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Nice and easy. I can see where I was using the wrong code. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer was useful to you or any of the others, can you please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you please explain the line 
AUD[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
I see *AUD[add this entry]* but I don't understand the indexes
thank you (again)

Comment: `split_line = line.split()` will split the line on empty spaces, Based on your text file you will have two elements in your list, so `AUD_EUR 0.72657` will become `[AUD_EUR, 0.72657]`. The first item in the list (`split_line[0]`) is your the string starting with `AUD` and the second item in the list is the associated value (`split_line[1]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
AUD = {}
with open("rates.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'AUD_' in line:
            key , value = line.lstrip('AUD_').split(' ')
            AUD[key] = value   
print AUD
```

This should do the trick. I changed your string "parser" to directly yield the currency in which to convert by removing 'AUD_' in the front. You could further improve your script, by picking the dictionary in which to write by taking the first 3 letters as the dictionary name.

Comment: Thanks for your time.... I'm getting "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"
I can see .append was not neccessary in my original too, so that's good to know.
thanks again

Comment: That happens, when split() only returns one value, because the line could not be split (e.g. empty line etc.). Solve that by try and catch around the lines in the loop or test your lines for empty lines etc. etc....

Answer (score 0):

You were not that far from answer.
Be sure to clean the data.
files often ends with an empty line, this may cause your split to fail.

```
data = """
AUD_CHF 0.77324
AUD_EUR 0.72657
AUD_GBP 0.61557
AUD_JPY 86.88
AUD_USD 0.76835
CAD_EUR 0.722459831
CAD_GBP 0.612726326
CAD_CHF 0.76915
CHF_EUR 0.939858457
CHF_GBP 0.795924865
"""

#remove empty lines
lines = [l for l in (line.strip() for line in data.split('\n')) if l ]

AUD = {}

for line in lines:
    #the two folowing lines could be in a function
    curencies, rate = line.split()
    cur1, cur2 = curencies.split('_')
    #debug
    #print cur1, '->', cur2, ' ', value

    if cur1 == 'AUD':
        AUD[cur2] =  rate


for currency, rate in AUD.items():
    print  '1 AUD =', rate, currency
```

in your core simply replace data.split('\n') by file.readlines().

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the notes so I can see what each line is doing. That's a lot closer to what I want it to do.... and thanks also for the tip about cleaning data.